# Angular - when calling a function from ng-show and passing a parameter into it - the parameter becomes undefined

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I am having a problem with Angular that when I call a function for ng-show to hide/show an element the parameter I pass to it is undefined from the function.

I don't know if it's because I am using PHP to print the HTML but I highly doubt it. There is no other option for me but to use it.

What could be a possible reason why it is undefined?

```
<div ng-app="App">
        <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    ...
    <?php
    ...
    echo '<li ng-show="toggle(' .$type . ')"></li>' //$type is not undefined
    ...     
?>   
    ...
    </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.toggle = function(type){
 console.log(type); //undefined
...

}

});
```

I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: PHP is server side language and angular js is client side. YOu can not achieve it in this way. You should use `ng-init`

Comment: The server side code builds the html and then angular is hooked into it since angular.js is loaded AFTER. I don't understand

Comment: What is `$type`'s datatype?

Comment: What do you see if you try to inspect the LI element? From what you are seeing, I would expect that the following is getting printed:

<li ng-show="toggle()"></li>

which would be a PHP error. Is it possible that the value of $type is and empty string?

Comment: @Stiliyan String 'ex'

Comment: @GPicazo It is toggle(something) where there is no string quotes...maybe that is why

Comment: @Krzysztof Safjanowski why did you completely change the OP's code? I reverted to the original posted code.

Comment: @JBNizet PHP has nothing in common with the problem and people are focusing on PHP instead of AngularJS and asynchronous code.

Comment: It definitely has to do with PHP, since the OP didn't understand that the quotes ending the PHP string wouldn't be inside the generated HTML, and doesn't have anything to do with  asynchronous code at all. The code you typed in your edition was radically different from the one the OP had, and radically different from the one he wanted to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is to pass a literal string to the toggle function, then you forgot to add quotes around the $type:

```
echo '<li ng-show="toggle(\'' .$type . '\')"></li>'
```

So, if the PHP variable `$type` has the value 'hello', the generated HTML code will be

```
<li ng-show="toggle('hello')"></li>
```

Without the quoted, the generated HTML code would be

```
<li ng-show="toggle(hello)"></li>
```

which means that the JavaScript function would be called with `$scope.hello` as argument, which is probably undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add quotes around the value being passed to your `toggle` function. If you don't then Angular will try to parse the value of your PHP `$type` variable as a variable on your controller scope which will be `undefined` because it does not exist:

```
<div ng-app="App">
        <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    ...
    <?php
    ...
    echo '<li ng-show="toggle(\"' .$type . '\")"></li>' //$type is not undefined
    ...     
?> 
...
</div>
</div>
```